# How can i remove \n\t from string in a List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net

Inside a loop over the List i did:

```
private void listtostringlist(List<NewsLine> lnl, List<string> myl)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < AllNews.Count; i++)
            {
                myl.Add(AllNews[i].text);
                IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact(AllNews[i].original_time, "DyyMMddTHHmm", provider);
                string results = myTime.ToString("hh:mm דווח במקור בתאריך : dd.MM.yy : שעה");
                AllNews[i].original_time = results;
                myl.Add(results);
                myl.Add(AllNews[i].link);
                myl[i] = Regex.Replace(myl[i], @"\t|\n|\r", "");
            }
```

Tried to use Regex:

```
myl[i] = Regex.Replace(myl[i], @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

But no effect some lines still i see when using a breakpoint in the List have \n\t in the beginning or end.
And i want to remove them if there are any.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4mSOz.jpg code is fine. it does remove those whitespaces.

Comment: Do you wan't to replace for example `\t` as _text_ or as _tab_? If you want to remove any tabs from the string you can't use the `@` before the string `\t` because then its getting escaped and it will search for the text `\t` not the tab.

Comment: @Kimmax: That's not right. The `\t` is understood as an escape sequence by the regular expression parser and so will interpret it as a tab. If you didn't use `@"\t"` you'd need to do `"\\t"`.

Comment: @Lamourou: That will only strip characters from the beginning and end. If there are any in the middle of the string they won't be removed by your method.

Comment: @Chris and if he wants to replace the _tab_ in his string (escape sequence `\t`) he will have to search for `\t` not `\\t`. Am I right?

Comment: @Kimmax: To remove tabs in his string he will need the regular expression to be `\t`. To get this the string will need to be defined as `@"\t"` or `"\\t"`. That is he is doing it correctly.

Comment: @chris Well that's what I said. What's wrong with my comment then? I asked him if he wants to replace an actual tab and if he wants to that he will have to use the non escaped `\t`. `If you want to remove any tabs from the string you can't use the @ before the string \t because then its getting escaped and it will search for the text \t not the tab.` Nothing other said.

Comment: @Kimmax: You said "If you want to remove any tabs from the string you can't use the @ before the string \t". This is wrong. You seemed to be confusing .NET's escaping of strings with the RE engine's escape sequences. If you are happy that `@"\t"` will search for a tab and not for the text `\t` then we are on the same page and I just misunderstood your intent.

Comment: @Chris well, same page then :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the count of `AllNews` is less than the count of lines in `myl` or that `myl` already has some lines in it when you pass it into this function.

If this is the case, then the counts won't match up and you wont get an iteration for each element in the collection, thus, not all elements will have the replace applied.

I'd rewrite it to this:

```
private void listtostringlist(List<NewsLine> lnl, List<string> myl)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < AllNews.Count; i++)
    {
          myl.Add(AllNews[i].text);
          // etc...
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < myl.Count; i++)
    {
        myl[i] = Regex.Replace(myl[i], @"\t|\n|\r", "");
    }
}
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you're also adding to `myl` multiple times in the `for` loop:

```
myl.Add(AllNews[i].text);
myl.Add(results);
myl.Add(AllNews[i].link);
```

This will mean that the counts of `AllNews` and `myl` will be out of sync so the indexer `i` is useless to `myl` given the context.

Comment: More particularly each iteration of the loop is calling `myl.Add` three times so even if it starts empty you will by the end of the loop have `3*count` entries in `myl` and be only stripping the special characters from the first `count` entries.

Comment: DGibbs this is working. I have another sub question please: After cleaning all this \n\t i want now to insert every 3 indexs in myl a empty string\line for example 0,1,2 so in index 3 to insert a new index empty one like space to seperate between index 3 and 4. Then 4,5,6 insert in index 7 empty string/space. Each every 3 indexs in the 4 to add empty string. Not to replace index 3 or index 7 or index 11 but to insert a new index that is empty. How can i do it ?

Comment: @DanielBarnatan: Do you mean after the three things you've added in each iteration of the loop? If so why not do `myl.Add(Environment.NewLine)` at the end of each iteration? It is definitely easier to add them as you go rather than afterwards.